# spring 404 controller not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a problem with spring, because I receive 404 error not found.

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/PROJECT_NAME/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


</web-app>
```

I have also mvc-dispatcher.xml file and my controller

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan
        base-package="com.PROJECT_NAME.web.controllers"/>


</beans>
```

and my controller

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

@RequestMapping(value="/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
ResponseEntity<Boolean> create() {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(true, HttpStatus.OK);
}

}
```

When I do query like localhost:8080/PROJECT_NAME/test I got 404 not found error. localhost:8080/PROJECT_NAME returns 200 status code
What is wrong ?

Comment: what's your context path?

Comment: right, the problem was with context path, because tomcat add it once , so request localhost:8080/PROJECT_NAME/PROJECT_NAME/test works. I will try to fix it myself. Thank you

Comment: you can set context path in your project META-INF/context.xml   <Context antiJARLocking="true" path="YOUR_CONTEXT_PATH"/>

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to mention context root in url-pattern. url-pattern should be `/`, which means any/every URL/request sholuld be served by dispatcher servlet.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

as you have mentioned url-pattern as `/PROJECT_NAME/*`, which means any URL  in the form `http://localhost:8080/PROJECT_NAME(Context_Root)/PROJECT_NAME/Anything` will be forwarded to dispatcher servlet and that's why `localhost:8080/PROJECT_NAME/PROJECT_NAME/test` is working fine.